# SQL Server : trigger error invalid object name 'deleted'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have the following problem: I'm trying to use a trigger that will insert all from logical table Delete into a new table (name of table from variable) 
The old trigger is always working but for this new one I get the following:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'DELETED'.

Code snippet with both triggers (first still working):

```
/* TRIGGER on dbo.tblSpending table to Create Backup/Clone - WORKING */
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CloneTable 
ON dbo.tblSpending
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT *
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
               WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
                 AND TABLE_NAME = 'tblSpendingRaw'))
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE dbo.tblSpendingRaw;     

        SELECT *
        INTO dbo.tblSpendingRaw
        FROM Deleted;
   END;
END;
GO
```

Trigger on `dbo.tblSpending` table that will create a new table `tblSpendingRaw + Date Stamp` for any UPDATE - NOT WORKING:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SaveTable 
ON dbo.tblSpending 
FOR UPDATE AS
BEGIN       
    DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @table_name = (SELECT 'tblSpendingRaw'
                              + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
                              + LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())), 3)
                              + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
                              + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
                              + CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
                              );

    EXEC('SELECT * INTO ' + @table_name + ' FROM Deleted');
END;
GO
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Gabriel

Comment: One word: **DON'T DO THIS!!** A trigger should be **very nimble, small, fast** - do **NOT** do any heavy processing or time-extensive work (like creating or dropping tables!) inside a trigger! Also: creating a new table for each single `UPDATE` seems rather excessive, too ...... rethink your code - change it - this code as is will never fly and never work reliably in a busy system

Comment: Thank you for the advice Marc, I'll never use this trigger on a production table it's just for testing where I have to try different ways to calculate loyalty points for a scheme. Gabriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the dynamic SQL  execute under a different scope, so you can not find the Inserted or Deleted magic table into this. So, You need to copy all records into temp table and then use the temp table into the dynamic query. Then your code some like that

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SaveTable 
ON dbo.tblSpending 
FOR UPDATE AS
BEGIN       
    DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @table_name = (SELECT 'tblSpendingRaw'
                              + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
                              + LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())), 3)
                              + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
                              + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
                              + CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
                              );
SELECT * INTO dbo.temptbl FROM Deleted; 
    EXEC('SELECT * INTO ' + @table_name + ' FROM temptbl');
     DROP TABLE dbo.temptbl;

END;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and solution Rahul, I'll never use this trigger on  a production table it's just for testing where I have to try different ways to calculate loyalty points for a scheme. So I find it handy to have historical snapshots to compare and ultimately to choose the most suitable way :) .